# Finding the average of a array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, average

I'm trying to find the average of quizzes using a function. I keep tweaking it but it just keeps returning 10. The premise of the program is to ask the user to submit their quizzes (which are out of 10). These are inputs are placed in a array `quizarray[]`. I then copy all the information from `quizarray` to another `tempArray` . tempArray is then sorted and used for the `calcQuizAverage` function. This function is supposed to return one of two averages. This is determined by the `numberOfQuizzes`

```
double calcQuizAverage(int quizArray[], int numberOfQuizzes) 
{ 
    int a;
    double avrg, sum, lowSum;
    a = 0;
    sum = 0;

    lowSum = quizArray[0] + quizArray[1];

    for (a=0; a< numberOfQuizzes; a++)
    {
        sum += double(quizArray[a]);
    }

    if (numberOfQuizzes <= 2)
    {
        avrg= double(((sum) / (10* numberOfQuizzes)) * 100);

        return avrg;
    }
    else if (numberOfQuizzes > 2)
    {
        avrg= double(((sum-lowSum) / (10* (numberOfQuizzes - 2)))*100);

        return avrg;
    }
}
```

I've checked if the sum and lowSum are what they are meant to be when the `numberOfQuizzes` is over 2 and it seemed fine. With the `numberOfQuizzes` less than or equal to 2, it just returns 10.

**Here's the rest of the code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

//Symbolic Constants

const int MAX=12;

//Function Prototypes

int buildQuizArray(int[]);
void printArray(string,int[],int);
double calcQuizAverage(int[],int);
void sortArray(int[],int);

int main ()
{
    int quizScores[MAX];
    int compQuiz;
    int tempArray[MAX];
    double average;
    int temp;
    int i;

    average = 0;

    compQuiz = buildQuizArray(quizScores);

    for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
         tempArray[i] = quizScores[i];
    }

    sortArray(tempArray, compQuiz);

    average = calcQuizAverage(tempArray, compQuiz);

    cout<<endl<<"Your quiz average is "<<average<<endl;

    printArray ("Quiz Scores", tempArray, compQuiz);



}



int buildQuizArray(int quizArray[])
{ 
    int numQuiz, input, a;
    a=0;
    numQuiz=1;

    cout << "Enter your score for quiz "<<numQuiz<<" (-1 to quit): ";
    cin >> input;

    while (input != -1)
    { 
        quizArray[a] = input;
        a++;
        numQuiz++;

        cout<< "Enter your score for quiz "<<numQuiz<<" (-1 to quit): ";
        cin >> input;

    } 
    return a+1;
} 



void printArray(string reportTitle, int quizArray[], int numberOfQuizzes)
{ 
    int a;

    cout<< endl <<reportTitle <<endl<<"-----------"<<endl;

    for (a=1; a<numberOfQuizzes; a++)
    {
        cout<< "Quiz " << a <<": " << setw(2) <<quizArray[a-1] <<"/10"<<endl;
    }
} 



double calcQuizAverage(int quizArray[], int numberOfQuizzes) 
{ 
    int a;
    double avrg, sum, lowSum;
    a = 0;
    sum = 0;

    lowSum = quizArray[0] + quizArray[1];

    for (a=0; a< numberOfQuizzes; a++)
    {
        sum += double(quizArray[a]);
    }

    if (numberOfQuizzes <= 2)
    {
        avrg= double(((sum) / (10* numberOfQuizzes)) * 100);

        return avrg;
    }
    else if (numberOfQuizzes > 2)
    {
        avrg= double(((sum-lowSum) / (10* (numberOfQuizzes - 2)))*100);

        return avrg;
    }
} 



void sortArray(int num[], int numberOfQuizzes) 
{ 
      int i, j, flag = 1;  
      int temp; 

      for(i = 1; (i <= numberOfQuizzes) && flag; i++)
     {
          flag = 0;
          for (j=0; j < (numberOfQuizzes -2); j++)
         {
               if (num[j+1] < num[j])
              { 
                    temp = num[j];
                    num[j] = num[j+1];
                    num[j+1] = temp;
                    flag = 1; 
               }
          }
     }
     return; 
}
```

Comment: 1.  You should cast before you divide, not after.  2.  What are the magic numbers 10 and 100?  100 I can understand if you're converting to percent.  Is 10 the maximum score per quiz or something?

Comment: yeah it is sorry. forgot to mention it. what do you mean by casting before i divide? <-novice

Comment: What should calcQuizAverage() return? Is the 'average of quizzes' equal to the average value in the parameter array?

Comment: Casting is an operation, and the parenthesis control the order of operations.  `double(a / b)` is different from `double(a) / b`

Comment: it should return the avrg. which is the average of the quizes in the parameter array.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use `vector<int>`? Or for that matter, `vector<float>` and save yourself the effort casting?

Comment: I think `return a+1;` should be `return a;`

Comment: Should be `return a;`, I think? It returns the number of quizzes entered (the last -1 value isn't counted), and not the bounds of the array. Incidentally problematic if `a` becomes greater than 11, but I guess that's a separate problem

Comment: i still have not gone over vectors, so I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `sum` variable is a double, you shouldn't need to cast in so many places.
Additionally, your code can be tidied by instead of using the form:

```
int a;
a=0;
for (a=0; ...) {
```

instead writing:

```
for (int a=0; ...) {
```

Your `buildQuizArray` function isn't returning the number of quizzes entered - I suspect you meant to write `return a;`, instead of `return a+1;` (This might be the key problem)

Regarding vectors, a `vector` is a container class that is available via the standard library, using `#include <vector>`. A vector can be grown as needed, and has a variety of useful functions, in particular `myVector.size()` returns the length of `myVector`. This would prevent the need to pass the size everywhere with your array. You also wouldn't need to allocated a specific 12 entries, allowing for a much simpler `sort` function (since you wouldn't have to avoid trailing zeros).

I would also recommend that your `lowSum` be calculated (and defined) only inside the `if` loop that it is used in - this reduces its scope (which isn't really a problem) and also means you won't have to calculate it unless it is going to be used (also not significant in a small program, but worth considering in general)

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!! Also, thanks for the quick lesson on vectors and suggesting the lowSum.

Answer (score 0):

Without further explanation it's not understandable what your code is supposed to do. According to the title, you want to calculate the average value in an array?
The following code will do that:

```
double calcQuizAverage(int quizArray[], int numberOfQuizzes){
  double avrg = 0.0;
  int a = 0;
  for (a = 0; a< numberOfQuizzes; a++){
    avrg += quizArray[a];
  }
  return avrg / static_cast<double>(numberOfQuizzes);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  int array[] = { 0, 1, 2};
  double x = calcQuizAverage(array, 3);
  return 0;
}
```

It's not clear, whats the reason for your additional if-clauses: your function should always return a value (you may want to replace the last 'else if' with just 'else'?).

Comment: ALthough `if`, `else if` isn't by definition inclusive of all possibilities, when could an int be both not `<=2` and also not `>2`?

Comment: @chrisb2244 Well - never, but as far as I know compilers are not guaranteed to notice that in this case. Falling off the end of a function that is declared to return a value (without explicitly returning a value) leads to undefined behaviour. gcc 4.9.0 will also complain with -Wall in these cases. See an example here: http://goo.gl/cISz5x

Answer (score 0):

```
avrg= double(((sum) / (10* numberOfQuizzes)) * 100);

e.g.
avrg = (sum/(numberofQuizzes*10.0))*100.0;
```